# Load AJAX inside of AJAX using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having a problem with the following code. It works fine up until the point where it starts to apply changes to the html that was loaded in the first ajax function.

Basically I'm trying to nest one ajax call inside another.

```
$(document).on("click", '#advertiser-email-submit', function(event) {
    $(this).blur();
    var email = $("#advertiser-email").val();

    $(".marketing").hide().html("");
    $("#stats-container").hide().html("");
    $("#advertiser-container").hide().html('<div style="height:64px;"><div class="col-md-5"></div><div class="col-md-1"><img src="https://www.example.com/images/spinner_white_green.gif"></div><div class="col-md-5"></div></div>').show();

    $.post("https://www.example.com/advertisers/interface/email/submit", {
            email: email
        },
        function(data, status) {
            if (status == "success") {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    //Load advertiser interface
                    $("#advertiser-container").hide().html(data).show();

                    //Load exchange visits list
                    var advertiser_id = $("#advertiser-overview").data("advertiser-id");

                    //THIS IS WHERE IT STARTS TO FAIL

                        $("#exchange-visits-container").hide().html('<div style="height:64px;"><div class="col-md-5"></div><div class="col-md-1"><img src="https://www.example.com/images/spinner_black_white.gif"></div><div class="col-md-5"></div></div>').show();
                        $.post("https://www.example.com/advertisers/interface/exchange/visits/list", {
                                advertiser_id: advertiser_id
                            },
                            function(data, status) {
                                if (status == "success") {
                                    if (data.length > 0) {
                                        $("#exchange-visits-container").hide().html(data).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: In *what way* does this actually fail?  What happens?  When you debug it, where does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior?

Comment: Remove the inner `$(function() { ... })` wrapping your code. It is a document ready handler.

Comment: @David it just does nothing

Comment: @Jasen does the same thing if I remove it. That was just my attempt to fix the problem.

Comment: @AmyNeville: The `$()` syntax tells it to set that function to the document's ready event handler.  I'm guessing it does exactly that.  However, since the document is already "ready" then that event will never fire again.  Are you trying to execute this code in a handler somewhere, or just execute it right away?  If the latter, then you can just write the code directly instead of wrapping it in an event handler.

Comment: @AmyNeville: Don't randomly wrap code on other random code to "attempt to fix the problem".  Debug it.  When you step through this in the debugger, observe what actually happens.  Does the code execute at all?  Is there an error?  Do the jQuery selectors find what you expect them to find?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  There is a lot that you can find out by debugging which we can't find out for you.

Comment: Use the browser's network monitor to examine these AJAX requests. What is the response from the first request and is the second request made?

Comment: You shouldn't re-use the same variable names in the second callback, either - if only for the sake of clarity.

Comment: There are no errors with the first AJAX. And no errors with the second AJAX either. Even the $("#exchange-visits-container").hide().html() line doesn't do anything even though the div is present. Which makes me think there's some problem with making html changes to what was loaded in the first AJAX.

Comment: @AmyNeville: Code doesn't simply *not execute*.  I'm afraid nobody here can debug this on your computer for you.  You're going to have to familiarize yourself with your browser's debugging tools to determine more specifically what's going on with the code.  "It doesn't work" doesn't really describe the problem in any meaningful way.

Comment: @David I think the problem is that the html that was written using AJAX can't be re-written. I'm asking if that is possible.

Comment: @AmyNeville: That's an incorrect conclusion.  The DOM can be modified regardless of what originally created it.  Once it's created, it makes no difference.

Comment: Ok sorry to have bothered you guys

Comment: I fixed it. It was my mistake. I feel silly but I honestly thought there was some DOM issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Your wrapping the inner function in a document ready instead of just calling the ajax

```
$(document).on("click", '#advertiser-email-submit', function(event) {
    $(this).blur();
    var email = $("#advertiser-email").val();

    $(".marketing").hide().html("");
    $("#stats-container").hide().html("");
    $("#advertiser-container").hide().html('<div style="height:64px;"><div class="col-md-5"></div><div class="col-md-1"><img src="https://www.example.com/images/spinner_white_green.gif"></div><div class="col-md-5"></div></div>').show();

    $.post("https://www.example.com/advertisers/interface/email/submit", {
        email: email
    },
    function(data, status) {
        if (status == "success") {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                //Load advertiser interface
                $("#advertiser-container").hide().html(data).show();

                //Load exchange visits list
                var advertiser_id = $("#advertiser-overview").data("advertiser-id");

                    var template = $('#templateId').removeAttr('id');
                    $("#exchange-visits-container").hide().html(template ).show();
                    $.post("https://www.example.com/advertisers/interface/exchange/visits/list", {
                        advertiser_id: advertiser_id
                    },
                    function(data, status) {
                        if (status == "success") {
                                if (data.length > 0) {
                                $("#exchange-visits-container").hide().html(data).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

            }
        }
    });
   return false;
});
```

Also it would be easier to debug and clean you code up if you used a template like this:

```
<div id="templateId" style="height:64px;"><div class="col-md-5">
   </div><div class="col-md-1"><img src="https://www.example.com/images/spinner_black_white.gif"></div>
   <div class="col-md-5"></div>
</div>
```

then you could set you html easier like this:

```
 var template = $('#templateId').removeAttr('id');
 $("#exchange-visits-container").hide().html(template ).show();
```

this is just an example so you should probably hide the template and then also make it visible

Comment: Thanks but it does the same thing if I do that. Nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure it's returning success? maybe add some error handlers

Comment: I don't think it's even making the call. $("#exchange-visits-container").hide().html() even this line isn't executing.

Comment: check to make sure your server is returning the correct html data.  You should just add some console.logs so you won't have to debug

Comment: @AmyNeville try the template pattern later too it will make all those nasty string html issues go away and it will be easier to maintain